# How do I save messages to txt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I try to save chat between me and customer to txt file I cannot figure it out because when I try to code it in it will save only 1 message at time and when someone else sends message it will rewrite the txt file example: I sent: What do you need help with?

```
In TXT: 
User: *me*
Message: *What do you need help with?*
Channel: *channel name*
```

But when he answers it it will rewrite the txt to his message

How I want it to be:

```
In TXT: 
User: *me*
Message: *What do you need help with?*
Channel: *channel name*
=======================================
User: *Customer*
Message: *Customer's reply*
Channel: *channel name*
=======================================
```

But I'll get:

```
In TXT:
User: *Customer*
Message: *Customer's reply*
Channel: *channel name*
```

I want to save all things we send but in txt it will save just the newest.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: please edit your question and post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to include the current version of your code that writes this text now so we can help show you what you need to change.

Comment: Saving messages without proper re-encryption and secure storage is against Discord TOS...just an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you did it before, but I would do it like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");

# FIRST MESSAGE
fs.writeFileSync("/1.txt", `User: ${username}\nMessage: ${messageContent}\nChannel: ${channelName}`)

# SECOND MESSAGE
let fileContent = fs.readFileSync("/1.txt").toString();
fs.writeFileSync("/1.txt", fileContent + `\n-\nUser: ${username}\nMessage: ${messageContent}\nChannel: ${channelName}`);

# and so on
```

Comment: It's unlikely  that `fs.writeFileSync()` is the correct solution for any server-side code.  And, you probably don't want to read the entire file only to write it out again.  Probablyl want to append new content to the existing file.  But, the OP needs to show us their current code so we can help them modify it.